# Prove that $n+10\cos n$ diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

How can you prove that $n+10\cos n$ diverges to infinity? I know how to use $M>0$, there exists $N$ greater than or equal to 0 such that...

Comment: You say you "know how to use M>0, there exists N greater than or equal to 0 such that...". That's all you need to do. What's stopping you?

Comment: An alternative is to show $\frac {f(n)}n\to 1$ by factoring $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$n + 10\cos n \geq n - 10$$ since $-1 \leq \cos n \leq 1$. Given $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n \geq b_n$ and $b_n$ diverges, can you show that $a_n$ diverges?